# Firefox and IE put padding/margins on <link/> elements. And weirdness with clearfix

Tags: html, css, browser, css-selectors

I had some problems with vertical spacing in Firefox and IE for an embarrassingly long time.

I am using a `*` selector in my css to apply margins to everything within a certain container element. Works fine in Chrome, however in FF and IE I was getting mysterious extra padding seemingly coming from nowhere, as you can observe here: http://jsfiddle.net/XrVXF/3/.

It turns out I had two separate problems. One is that non-Chrome browsers will select  elements with the `*` selector and apply the margins and *the margins show up in the browser!* even though the element is invisible to things like Firebug. **Should this be considered a bug?** You may be asking what business is a link element doing inside the body tag. Well I could probably avoid it but it is the easiest way to do some things on my site. [This page](http://www.tutorialchip.com/tutorials/html5-block-level-elements-complete-list/) says that the `*` selector should only apply to block level elements in HTML5, which I am using, so in that sense it seems to me that Firefox at least is bugging out, and IE too if they are supposed to have proper HTML5 support yet. Now that I know this I can work around it but **maybe there are other elements I should worry about too?** (Doesn't seem to apply to script or style tags.) **Would I be better off applying margins to a large list of html elements instead of `*`?**

The other weird thing, which you can observe in the fiddle I linked is that the clearfix on the bottom (which is not necessary in the example, but is on my site) also picks up the margins and applies them in FF and IE but not in Chrome. **Which is the 'right' behaviour?** Strangely, I noticed that turning off overflow:hidden, prevents the clearfix from taking up space, and doesn't seem to have any detrimental effect on my site. **What is overflow set to hidden for?**

**Correction:** Oops, I was using .clear when I meant to be using .clearfix (which appends content after your floated stuff), which seems to work fine and doesn't have margin issues.

Comment: You're reading that page wrong. The `*` it's referring to is not the universal selector. It's just an asterisk mark to denote certain special elements that are in HTML5.

Comment: Also, the `*` selector applies to *any* element. This includes `html`, `head`, `body`, and anything inside those elements. It has nothing to do with HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Should this be considered a bug?**

Considering you're applying styles to elements that are in places that they shouldn't be in the first place (`link` in `body`???), this is anybody's guess. The likely reason why they don't show up in Firebug is because Firebug isn't expecting them to be there.

In all seriousness, my best guess as to what's going on in your fiddle is:

- Chrome has a UA style for `link` elements to `display: none`. I imagine it does the same for any other elements that belong in the `head` element and not `body`.
- Other browsers have no default `display` style for `link` elements, instead relying on `head` to have `display: none` to hide everything that belongs in the `head` element as well. So when you place a `link` within `body`, it shows up with the margins because it's showing up with the initial value of `display: inline`.

  FWIW, if you give it a style of `display: block`, [its margins will collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) and it'll have the same apparent effect as if it had `display: none` as in Chrome.

Again, this is based on invalid markup in your fiddle, so I can't say which browser, if *any*, is right or wrong since all the spec says is that the page head should not be rendered. Also, cue arguments/debates on whether this is a reason not to use the `*` selector, or a reason not to write invalid HTML, or both...

Comment: OK, I misread the second part of your question... I have no idea why the clearfix behaves like that. Or maybe I'm just not thinking clearly because it's getting late...

Comment: Hmm, I tried applying margins to a rather large but hopefully comprehensive list of elements I want to have margins on, like so: `.container div, .container p, .container h1 .... {margin: 10px}`. The problem now is that I can't override those margins with a simple class or element selector because the `parent child` selector is more specific... Still not sure what the best solution for this is.