# Is it possible to make all elements on the page a display: flex (flexbox)?

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to use flexbox for an app, and want all elements to be set do display: flex. Is that possible? if yes, how? I have alread set body { display: flex }, but it still does not apply to all body elements.

Comment: Wouldn't the [universal selector](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006a.html) do the trick? `* { display: flex; }`

Comment: 1. Wouldnt that lead to performance issues? 2. Is it better practice than applying display:flex to every tag?

Comment: 1. Yes, it probably would lead to (negligible, tiny, almost immeasurable) performance issues, but it's by far the simplest way of doing what you asked (given that the `display` property isn't inherited). 2. It strikes me that a selector consisting of a massive list of all HTML elements would take quite a long time to download and parse, too! As for best practise, I don't think either of them is a particularly awesome idea, but I don't know the details of your implementation.

Comment: Benchmark it and find out?  There's not a whole lot of effort here behind this question.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer @OllyHodgson. Why are not display property inherited?

Comment: @AndyH Because it would wreak havoc :) The `<a>` element is an inline element. If it inherited `display: block;` from it's parent elements, all links would be full width and cause a line break (like a `p`, `h1` or `div`). The rather complicated CSS2 spec is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#inheritance

Comment: I can't think of a legitimate reason to be applying `display: flex` to every single element. What problem are you trying to solve? Why *must* everything be a flex container? If performance is such a concern, don't do it until you have a very good reason to do so.

Comment: @BoltClock like many other platforms. Layout consistancy.

Comment: @Oliver Dixon: I disagree. Not everything needs to be a flex container for layout consistency. If anything I'd say it introduces more inconsistencies than fixes them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(I took my comments and turned them into an answer)

The [universal selector](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006a.html) would do the trick:

```
body * { display: flex; }
```

(Note that I've scoped it to only include elements within the `body`)

The universal selector can [lead to (negligible, tiny, almost immeasurable) performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951997/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-csss-universal-selector), but it's by far the simplest way of doing what you asked (given that the `display` property isn't inherited). The other option (a selector consisting of a massive list of all HTML) elements would take quite a long time to download and parse, too! As for best practise, I don't think either of them is a particularly awesome idea, but I don't know the details of your implementation.

The `display` property isn't inherited because it would wreak havoc! For example, the `<a>` element is an inline element. If it inherited `display: block;` from it's parent elements, all links would be full width and cause a line break (like a `p`, `h1` or `div`). The inheritance bit of the (rather complicated) CSS2 spec is here: http://w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#inheritance

Comment: You'll want to limit the scope to elements within `body` at least, otherwise `head` and all its contents will have the same `display: flex` style applied to them, and depending on the browser this may or may not have unwanted side effects. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126320/firefox-and-ie-put-padding-margins-on-link-elements-and-weirdness-with-clear/12126353#12126353

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, very good point. I've adjusted the answer accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

body { display: flex; }   it will not work because it means apply flex to body.

instead

- {display: flex;}    it means apply flex to all element(selectors) in page. however I faced issue if using live server because it will apply flex to  element also which is automatically applied to code editor(mine is vs code).

you can use this method

anyelement,.anyclass,#anyelement {display:flex;}    adding comma after selectors means apply flex to all element which is written.