# Using The *-Selector In Codepen Will Alter The Preview

Tags: css

This might not be a traditional CSS question, but is definetly the cause of the issue.

Anyways - when I was setting up a Codepen example and typed in the following rules:

```
*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  display: flex;
}
```

It returned **this** as raw text in the preview:

```
CodePen Demo*, ::after, ::before { box-sizing: border-box; } * { display: flex; }//# sourceURL=pen.js
```

---

Now adding any CSS & HTML will preview like this:

```
<div>Div</div>

---

*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  display: flex;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Georgia';
}

---

 CodePen Demo*, ::after, ::before { box-sizing: border-box; } * { display: flex; } html { font-family: 'Georgia'; } Div//# sourceURL=pen.js
```

**Reloading** or **switching** **browsers** does not help it, but only worsen it:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the link to your pen(which currently has this issue)?

Comment: @PraneetDixit, Sure. Its this one: https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/MWeRyOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the bug is here -

```
*{
    display: flex;
}
```

You are applying the `display: flex` property in the universal selector, which may have [many weird consequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126320/firefox-and-ie-put-padding-margins-on-link-elements-and-weirdness-with-clear/12126353#12126353).

So, the simple solutions is to apply the `display: flex` property on the `body` tag and the specific tags on which you want it. Some extra code can save you from unwanted results.

You can check my pen [here](https://codepen.io/PraneetDixit/pen/bGeJegQ). All I have changed is just the `*` with `body` in css.

**EDIT** - Using universal selector inside the body tag may still have weird consequences because then, if any script or even comments are included in your `body` tag, then you will see something like this -

```css
body *{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
       Some text
    </div>
    <script> <!--Here comes the problem-->
      function hi(){
        alert("Hi");
      }
    </script>
</body>
```

So, it would be better not to use the `*` selector. You can always change the property of every element manually/separately.

Comment: Exactly. `flex` property must not be used with the universal selector. It has to produce bugs as `*` selects even `<head>`, `<meta>`, etc. which can't be a flexbox, right?

Comment: @ShounakDas Absolutely

Comment: @Simplicius Even this may have some side-effects. Check my edited answer.

Comment: The `display` property should not used with the universal selector. If you want to make multiple elements a flexbox, then you should use a `flex` class and add it to all those elements in html. Properties like `margin` and `padding` are safe to use with `*`.

Comment: @ShounakDas Yes

Comment: You can also use `box-sizing` and `font-size` properties to `*`.